# How to use Gists code snippet feature in ckEditor?

Tags: javascript, jsf, ckeditor, gist, primefaces-extensions

To create the blog post, I have text editor (ckEditor) as below.
[image]

Code:

```
<h:form>

        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

        <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{EditorController.content}"
            interfaceColor="#{EditorController.color}" checkDirtyInterval="0">
            <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{EditorController.saveListener}"
                update="growl" />
        </pe:ckEditor>

        <p:commandButton action="#{EditorController.changeColor}"
            update="editor" value="Change color with AJAX"
            style="margin-top:10px;" />

    </h:form>
```

I saved this `content` as `String` in backing bean as below:

```
private String content;
public void saveListener() {

content = content.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
}
```

Outputted screen as below:
[image]

Code:

```
<h:body>
        Hello World Result!

    <br />

    <h:outputText id="outformat" value="#{EditorController.content}" escape="false" />

</h:body>
```

But I expected to see gists code snippet in this line `"<script src="https://gist.github.com/YeWin/f906ab9eb22a1af06a8c4549cafc9a33.js?file=helloworld.java"></script>"`

Like below:[image]

The question is how can I add these gists code snippet feature in my JSF Primefaces extension ckEditor.? It's possible or there is something I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the `Source` button.
2. Then paste the HTML code (`<script src=... ></script>`) in the pop up
   window.
3. Click `ok`.

For more information, see ckeditor's [sourcedialog](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.2/samples/plugins/sourcedialog/sourcedialog.html) documentation.

[image]

Comment: After click ok, <script src=... ></script> source is disappear in editor and can't carry to bean.

Comment: advancedContentFilter="false" attribute in pe:ckeditor help to solve this problem. I accept your answer now. thanks.